# How to switch between outputs attached to same sound card without detaching one output

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones, speakers

I am busy moving from Windows to Kubuntu. So far the only thing standing in my way of successfully losing windows is the limitation of sound configuration on linux.

I want to be able to have both speakers plugged in (in the rear port) and headphones plugged in (in the front port) and then switch between them via software settings/programmatically (eventually I want to make it a single shortcut for extra efficiency). So far this is not possible. One has to physically unplug the headphones to let the sound work through the speakers. Even if I chose line out (over headphones) in the settings after plugging in the headphones it doesn't work, in fact at this point nothing works. If I have both speakers and headphones plugged in and I chose line out then no sound comes anywhere but if I choose headphones the sound comes  through the headphones.

From googling it seems that people have lots of different issues with sound on linux. Lots of people say it's a hardware limitation however this is not true (at least for me), as this works perfectly on windows.

This is a stupid thing to hold me back from dropping windows, but continuously having to plug/unplug my headphones will wear it out unnecessarily as my front audio jack is already not the best.

EDIT 1: The output is quite long so I put it in a pastebin.
`amixer scontents`: http://pastebin.com/wiB1m0RW

Comment: Show the output of `amixer scontents` for your device.

Comment: see my edit, I added a link to http://pastebin.com/wiB1m0RW

Comment: Disable `Auto-Mute Mode`.

Comment: disabling auto-mute prevents me from choosing which device I want sound from, instead it streams sound to every device, whether I choose line out or headphones in my sound settings. This is not what I'm looking for. I'm simply looking to make the settings work as intended, ie. If I choose line out it should output sound to my speakers, if I choose headphones it should output sound to my headphones.

Answer (score 0):

Install "Pulse audio volume control" (pavucontrol):
In the the device output tab, you can  usually  force "port"  to line , headphone or speaker.

Comment: there is no "force", only the same options as the normal settings, and it doesn't do anything differently. Pavucontrol does show one thing though. In the "port" options next to each option it says "plugged in" or "unplugged". When I plug in the headphones it shows headphones as plugged in and line out as unplugged (even though my speakers are plugged into line out). This must be a low level driver issue with linux, as it works on windows but looks almost like a hardware limitation on linux.